# Same function in vue wrong in react

Tags: reactjs, vue.js

I have a JWT Authentication in Vue(works) and im trying to change to React(its the same backend).
In console.log(this.state.email) i get the correct email, same with the password.
i think the problem is in the 'try{const response = await axios.post("api/auth/login"...'
I cant pass thro in the React only in Vue

React wrong:

```
  EnvioLogin = async () => {
    console.log(this.state.email)
    console.log(this.state.password)
    try {
      const response = await axios.post("api/auth/login", { email: this.state.email, password: this.state.password });
      localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
      if (response.status === "200") {
        this.getUsers();
        console.log(response);
        this.props.history.push("/app");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({ error: "User or Password wrong!" });
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ error: "" });
      }, 2000);
    }
  };
```

Vue correct:

```
async EnvioLogin() {
  try {
    console.log(this.email);
    console.log(this.password);
    const response = await axios.post("api/auth/login", {
      email: this.email,
      password: this.password,
      
    });
            localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
    if (response.status == "200") {
      this.getUsers();
      console.log(response);
      this.$router.push("intermediorotas");
      this.showLogin = false;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    this.showError = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.showError = false;
    }, 2000);
  }
},
```

Comment: what does "wrong" mean?? are you getting an error?

Comment: What is printed to the console or what error did you get ?

Comment: EnvioLogin doing sth different with routing and showLoging in 200 status if statement in vue and react.

Comment: Sorry about that. "React Wrong" its where the Error is XD. Im not getting any erros in the console log or inspect. When the code gets in the try doesnt pass just stop