# Same function in vue and react but doesnt work in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

Im doing the same login function in React/Vue.
It works fine on VueJS but when i use in ReactJS it doesnt work.

Vue working fine:

```
async EnvioLogin() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post("api/auth/login", {
      email: this.email,
      password: this.password,
    });
    localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
    if (response.status == "200") {
      this.getUsers();
      console.log(response);
      this.$router.push("intermediorotas");
      this.showLogin = false;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    this.showError = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.showError = false;
    }, 2000);
  }
},
```

},

React doesnt working:

```
    EnvioLogin = async () => {
        try {
          const response = await axios.post("api/auth/login", { email: this.state.email, password: this.state.password });
          localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
          if (response.status === "200") {
            this.getUsers();
            console.log(response);
            this.props.history.push("/app");
          }
        } catch (error) {
          this.setState({ error: "User or Password wrong!" });
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({ error: "" });
          }, 2000);
        }
      };
```

I used console.log in both try{} and both variables(email/password) are getting there in both cases and in the browser no errors appears..
I think the problem is in the

```
    const response = await axios.post("api/auth/login", { email: this.state.email, password: this.state.password });
      localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
```

getUsers vue:

```
  methods: {
    async getUsers() {
      const response = await axios.get("api/alunos", {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
        },
      });

  console.log(response);
},
```

getUsers React:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getUsers()
  }

  getUsers = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get("api/alunos", {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
      },
    });

    console.log(response);
  };
```

Comment: In React you use arrow functions, from my understanding, arrow functions don't have the right context.

Comment: This is the same as your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66181175/same-function-in-vue-wrong-in-react). Please don't post duplicate questions that simply add details or to give it a bump.

Answer (score 1):

In js, `this` behaves differently in ordinary function and arrow function. And there is also difference between strict mode and non-strict mode.

Specially, arrow function don't bind to the caller's context. If your function/the lib you use actually depends on this behaviour, it would create some very obscure bug.

Your 2 functions are defined differently. The first one is ordinary function and the second one is arrow function. and they also reference this.

You could check on the usage of `this` first. But it will be hard to understand the problem without more context/reproducible code.

SEE: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: Its a Login with JWT. In both i use the same axios.js file with only this: import axios from 'axios'

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/';

Comment: The variables are differente, in React i use state{email:"", password:""} and in Vue i create them without the state.

Comment: what I meant is `this` in `this.getUser()` is referring to different things. But without knowing the error message, context, and how the other parts are implemented, it would be hard to know the problem

Comment: I edit with the post with getUsers()...about the erros when i inspect in the browser doent get any errors but pass right thro the end after getting in "const responde = await axios.post("api/auth/login",..." after that the function ends.

Comment: Is it going into the catch block? what the `setState({ error })` would actually do?

Comment: seanplwong, thanks for the help. I will try to do another from the 0, no erros appears...just didnt work. Thank you so much for trying to help me.